# apache .htaccess rule with dynamic pages (php) performance

Tags: php, mysql, performance, .htaccess

i have a new website (i'm building one right now) and i want to make sure i do it correctly and not redesigning after 1 month.

so i have pages like:

```
/candy
/candy/chocolate
/drink
/drink/beer
```

so i look on stackoverflow about how can i do this and i found:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
```

now, this will work but my question is about execution. obviously the $_GET[category] will be the name and page will be chocolate for example.

now when i do my query i will do:

```
$sql = "SELECT myfields FROM mytable WHERE name = '" . $_GET['category'] . "'";
```

now, would it be better if i use the primary key which is an INT. if so, what can i do in my .htaccess to do this?

Comment: If name is unique, then it doesn't matter. If name is not unique, you are in deep shit.

Comment: @bianca: would you mind URL like stackoverflow use: /id/category/page? like: /123/candy/chocolate/ which the key of candy and chocolate is unique and 123 is the last page in this case chocolate ID?

Comment: i would preferably not since but if its the only option then i guess so.

Comment: you have access to the `httpd.conf` or `apache2.conf`?

Comment: you can try to use `locate httpd.conf` or what type of hosting you have?

Comment: i dont knwo what is this locate httpd.conf and i have a Economy hosting with godaddy.com

Comment: oh then no you don't have access to this apache files (which are config).

Comment: Please read up on [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately using a name and convert it to a unique id might take longer to execute than creating an index on the name itself.

Here's what I recommend based on the urls you have:

**Add a index to the name of the page**

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` ADD key indexname (columnname);
```

example:

```
ALTER TABLE `page` ADD key pagename (name);
```

Now, because the structure is different `/candy` vs `/candy/chocolate`, I assume you have some sort of structure like a main page with the list (/candy) and specific list (/candychocolate) so in this case you can use this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1&page=list [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
```

Then you can simply query the category and the page using the indexed field. This will fast (of course not as fast as an INT but still fast).

For the first query you can do:

```
$name = addslahes($name);
SELECT fields FROM category WHERE category = '$name';
```

and when you get a page you can use:

```
$categoryname = addslahes($categoryname);
$pagename = addslahes($pagename);
SELECT fields FROM page LEFT JOIN category ON (page.categoryid = category.id) WHERE page = '$pagename' AND category = '$categoryname';
```

this way, by using both category and page, you will avoid page not found (404).

Answer (score 3):

Just make sure your database has an [index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) for the name row. That will make the lookup just as fast as using a integer primary key.

Use something like `CREATE INDEX name ON mytable` I think, but doing it via phpmyadmin is a lot easier.

Also protect the script from sql injection by using addslashes

```
$sql = "SELECT myfields FROM mytable WHERE name = '" . addslashes($_GET['category']) . "'";
```

Comment: The "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE name = '" . $_GET['category'] . "'" part is certainly more worthy to mention than the original question itself! _Please_, protect your code from SQL injection, _do_ _not_ just stuff user input in your SQL queries. You can add more protection by selecting all category names from DB first and then checking if `$_GET['category']` is known category name by something like `array_key_exists`.

Comment: @hijarian Don't see how that is more secure than addslashes. There is no way of injecting code either way, and addslashes is a lot shorter. Some people would suggest using mysql_real_escape_string, but that only matters if you use a characterset other that ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

The identifier used in URL should be unique and have a database index. If both the ID and category name are unique and indexed, then it's performance-wise the same, but I would recommend using the name as it is more search engine-friendly and descriptive than an internal ID, which becames especially important when a URL is displayed somewhere without much additional context (eg., `example.org/1` vs. `example.org/shoes` printed in a newspaper). If not, then use ID and change the rewrite rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
```

(Btw, `\d+` should also be used for `page` if it is numeric.)